# Determine the exact number of subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_{924}$ with addition

Tags: abstract-algebra, cyclic-groups

Determine the exact number of subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_{924}$  with addition

I know the group $(\mathbb{Z}_n, +)$ is cyclic. I realize how to find the number of elements of $\mathbb{Z}_{20}$ for say, but I am stuck on this. Can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the canonical projection $\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z_n$, the subgroups of $\mathbb Z_n$ correspond to the subgroups of $\mathbb Z$ containing $n\mathbb Z$ and these are of the form  $d\mathbb Z$ where $d$ divides $n$.

Therefore, you only have to count the number of divisors of $924 = 2^2 \cdot 3 \cdot 7 \cdot 11$.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I see this now.